# (2.8) Bevel tool not duplicating edge correctly

Tags: edges, bevel

I apologize if the title doesn't get the problem across properly, I'm new to blender so not very familiar with the correct terminology, and not a native english speaker.

When I try to bevel the edge shown in the following image, this happens:

[image]
As you can see, it's in same dimension. It's supposed to duplicate across Z and horizontal axis, but it doesn't?

When I do the exact same thing with other edges, there is no problem:

[image]

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate vertices: select all in edit mode and alt+M by distance.

Comment: You should also delete your loose geometry. Select > Select All by Trait > Loose Geometry.

Comment: thank you @lemon and @barkest! it works now